# I have images that are available to my view 80-90% of the time because they don't always populate the dataSource fast enough. How can I fix this?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiimage, nsmutablearray

I have a detail view controller that is presented by a collection view controller full of items. Some of these items have a single image and some have additional images (images of different angles of the piece of clothing).

When I segue to the detail view controller I have to quickly communicate with my external database. Firstly I check if there are additional images and if there are I store them in an NSMutableArray.

The array isn't populate with the images fast enough so I have to reloadData in my viewDidAppear method.

This works 80-90% of the time but there are sometimes the it doesn't and I'm left with the spinner I put in view but no image. I then have to go back a controller and come back to the detail view controller for the image to show. This is the only obvious issue in my app. I don't think it's a good look and sure there is a way to stop this.

I thought of maybe loaded all resources when the app is first opened. So load all images in the background. However what happens as the clients store grows and they have thousands of clothes in their store. Might be a problem. I also thought about loaded the images in the previous controller but the only way I can know which set of images to load and store in an array would be when the collection view cell is tapped. If the customer arrives on the page and taps an image straight away the array might not be ready.

**Here is how I load the images and store in an array.**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Load up additional images
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Garments"];
    [query whereKey:@"title" equalTo:[self garmentTitle]];
    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

        [[self carouselSpinner] startAnimating];
        if (!error) {

            // Set objectID for save to favourite feature
            _garmentObject = object;

            PFFile *additionalImage1 = [object objectForKey:@"image2"];
            PFFile *additionalImage2 = [object objectForKey:@"image3"];
            PFFile *additionalImage3 = [object objectForKey:@"image4"];
            PFFile *additionalImage4 = [object objectForKey:@"image5"];
            PFFile *additionalImage5 = [object objectForKey:@"image6"];

            [_additionalGarmentImagesArray addObject:[self garmentImage]];

            if (additionalImage1) {

                PFImageView *pfImageView1 = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
                [pfImageView1 setFile:additionalImage1];
                [pfImageView1 loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        [_additionalGarmentImagesArray addObject:image];

                    }

                }];
            }

            if (additionalImage2) {

                PFImageView *pfImageView2 = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
                [pfImageView2 setFile:additionalImage2];
                [pfImageView2 loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        [_additionalGarmentImagesArray addObject:image];
                    }

                }];
            }

            if (additionalImage3) {

                PFImageView *pfImageView3 = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
                [pfImageView3 setFile:additionalImage3];
                [pfImageView3 loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        [_additionalGarmentImagesArray addObject:image];
                    }

                }];
            }

            if (additionalImage4) {

                PFImageView *pfImageView4 = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
                [pfImageView4 setFile:additionalImage4];
                [pfImageView4 loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        [_additionalGarmentImagesArray addObject:image];
                    }

                }];
            }

            if (additionalImage5) {

                PFImageView *pfImageView5 = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
                [pfImageView5 setFile:additionalImage5];
                [pfImageView5 loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        [_additionalGarmentImagesArray addObject:image];
                    }

                }];
            }



        } else {
            NSLog(@"emp array");
        }
```

**Array is populated by the time this method is called:**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[self carousel] reloadData];
}
```

**Finally I use my array of images:**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    //return the total number of items in the carousel

    return [_additionalGarmentImagesArray count];
}
```

**and here:**

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{


    PFImageView *imageView = [[PFImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300.0f, 354)];
    view = imageView;

    //create new view if no view is available for recycling
    if (view == nil)
    {
        //set image
        ((PFImageView *)view).image = _additionalGarmentImagesArray[index];
        [[self carouselSpinner] stopAnimating];
    } else {
        //set image
        ((PFImageView *)view).image = _additionalGarmentImagesArray[index];
        [[self carouselSpinner] stopAnimating];
    }


    return view;
}
```

Anothing thing that popped to mind was maybe in my segue of the previous controller I could get the data from my backend in the background and use a completion block. So if the data was grabbed then segue to the detail view controller if not then do nothing. All during the wait a spinner will show.

How would you deal with my issue?

Right now each image is stored in it's own column in the database e.g. image2, image3, image4, image5. I was thinking again maybe store them in an array? But I'm not sure how much time that would buy me and if it would even stop the issue I'm having with failed loads. My collection view images are taken from the backend to but yet they never ever fail to load.

Would appreciate some solid advice or solution if possible

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I loaded additional images and stored them in an array in my cellForItemAtIndexPath method of my collectionView (controller that presenting detailView).

I then passed that array to a property of my detailView during the segue process and my array of images were available immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to firstly get from the server the URLs for all the images you want to display so you can know how many cells to configure in you table view or collection view.

Then create custom cells with a UIImageView property for displaying the thumbnail image or so.
Also, another property NSDictionary *imageInfo; which you will set with different details including the URL for the corresponding cell's image.
When you set the imageInfo property from you view controller class, the cell object will download the image async (in the background). Do that by overriding the setter for imageInfo property.

After downloading an image, you need to update the UI in the main thread(this is done in the custom cell):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  self.imageView.image = image;
});
```

This way, whenever the image is finished downloading, the UI will get updated.

You can also cache images if you need, and also clear the cache from time to time.

You may consider the methods called when the cells disappear from the scree, in that cases you can cancel any download, because obviously you do not need that anymore if it is not visible.

Hope it makes sense

Comment: I use PFImageView to do exactly what you state above. http://blog.parse.com/2012/07/11/loading-remote-images-stored-on-parse/

Answer (score 0):

From how I am understanding it, you want to make sure that `[[self carousel] reloadData];` is always called after all 5 `pfImageViewX loadInBackground:` background methods are completed correct?

This is how I'd do it and I wouldn't change much:

I'd add a counter in your background fetch called `numImagesChecked` and increment it after each of the 5 images are checked.

Then, I'd wrap `[[self carousel] reloadData];` in another function, that will only execute the reloadData if `numImagesChecked` is 5 (i.e. all additionalImages were checked and completed)

Here it is modified in your viewDidLoad:

```
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

        [[self carouselSpinner] startAnimating];
        if (!error) {

            // Set objectID for save to favourite feature
            _garmentObject = object;

            PFFile *additionalImage1 = [object objectForKey:@"image2"];
            PFFile *additionalImage2 = [object objectForKey:@"image3"];
            PFFile *additionalImage3 = [object objectForKey:@"image4"];
            PFFile *additionalImage4 = [object objectForKey:@"image5"];
            PFFile *additionalImage5 = [object objectForKey:@"image6"];

            [_additionalGarmentImagesArray addObject:[self garmentImage]];

            int numImagesChecked = 0; //add this

            if (additionalImage1) {

                PFImageView *pfImageView1 = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
                [pfImageView1 setFile:additionalImage1];
                [pfImageView1 loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        [_additionalGarmentImagesArray addObject:image];

                    }
                    numImagesChecked++;
                    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadDataWithCounter:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:numImagesChecked] waitUntilDone:NO];
                }];
            }
            else {
                numImagesChecked++;
            }

            if (additionalImage2) {

                PFImageView *pfImageView2 = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
                [pfImageView2 setFile:additionalImage2];
                [pfImageView2 loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        [_additionalGarmentImagesArray addObject:image];
                    }
                    numImagesChecked++;
                    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadDataWithCounter:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:numImagesChecked] waitUntilDone:NO];
                }];
            }
            else {
                numImagesChecked++;
            }

            if (additionalImage3) {

                PFImageView *pfImageView3 = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
                [pfImageView3 setFile:additionalImage3];
                [pfImageView3 loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        [_additionalGarmentImagesArray addObject:image];
                    }
                    numImagesChecked++;
                    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadDataWithCounter:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:numImagesChecked] waitUntilDone:NO];
                }];
            }
            else {
                numImagesChecked++;
            }

            if (additionalImage4) {

                PFImageView *pfImageView4 = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
                [pfImageView4 setFile:additionalImage4];
                [pfImageView4 loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        [_additionalGarmentImagesArray addObject:image];
                    }
                    numImagesChecked++;
                    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadDataWithCounter:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:numImagesChecked] waitUntilDone:NO];
                }];
            }
            else {
                numImagesChecked++;
            }

            if (additionalImage5) {

                PFImageView *pfImageView5 = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
                [pfImageView5 setFile:additionalImage5];
                [pfImageView5 loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        [_additionalGarmentImagesArray addObject:image];
                    }
                    numImagesChecked++;
                    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadDataWithCounter:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:numImagesChecked] waitUntilDone:NO];
                }];
            }
            else {
                numImagesChecked++;
            }

            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadDataWithCounter:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:numImagesChecked] waitUntilDone:NO];



        } else {
            NSLog(@"emp array");
        }
```

Here is the new function:

```
-(void)reloadDataWithCounter:(NSNumber *)imagesChecked
{
    if([imagesChecked intValue]>4){ //only reload data after all 5 images have been checked
        [[self carousel] reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is sometimes there can be 4 images, sometimes maybe 2. It really varies how many additional images the administrator has uploaded for that piece of clothing. So I to some how need to count how many additional images in the return object e.g. if additionlImage1, if additionalImage2 etc then compare that to the _additionalGarmentImagesArray and once the match that means all images were loaded. Then I can reloadData. Basically I need a way for the code you supplied above to work if we don't know how many images will be returned because the amount varies.

Comment: Are you not always checking for 5 images though? Even if there is only 1 or 2 or zero you are always checking for 5 right? The counter will always finish at 5. It is not meant to count how many images, just how many images were CHECKED. This is why it also increments on the "else" for each image check.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Pavlusha - use the URLs from the PFFile objects. You can then utilize the fabulous AFNetworking UIImageView [category](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.3.1/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html) to load the images asynchronously.

Comment: But the PFImageView view is doing just that. It loads images asynchronously.